# URL being called wrong in php

Tags: php, php-carbon

I am creating a string URL to be called from an external API, first I am getting two dates, start and end:

```
$start = new Carbon($request->date_start);
$end = new Carbon($request->date_end);
```

Only date values are being passed through the $request object (25/06/2016).

I then use these values in a URL string:

```
$url = "https://www.api.com/KML/PositionHistory?fromDate=" . $start->toDateTimeString() . "&toDate=" . $end->addHours(24)->toDateTimeString();
```

Calling the url:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
```

This is where I get the error because it tries to call the following URL:

```
https://www.api.com/KML/PositionHistory?fromDate=2016-07-17 00:00:00&amp;toDate=2016-08-01 00:00:00
```

It is creating the `&amp;` strings, how would I go about fixing this?

Note that the time at the end of the dates are required.

Edit:

Using `urlencode` on the timestamps and trimming `$url` before the call results in the following error:

```
file_get_contents(https://www.api.com/KML/PositionHistory?fromDate=2016-07-17+00%3A00%3A00&amp;toDate=2016-08-01+00%3A00%3A00):

failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Okay so here is what got it to work as as responded by `entiendoNull`:

Simply do the URL building using `http_build_query`

```
$arr = [
           'fromDate' => $start->toDateTimeString(),
           'toDate'   => $end->addHours(24)->toDateTimeString(),
       ];

$url = "https://www.api.com/KML/LatestPositions?" . http_build_query($arr);

$contents = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: @Anant, that last `"` that you added to your example is wrong and should not be there. Riaan, what if you use `http_build_query($arr,'','&')` to build your query, where `$arr` is an array containing parameters and their values?

Comment: @Anant Hi Anant, the spaces are before and after the . only and not inside the quotation marks, so for readability only, they don't affect the spacing inside of the strings.

Comment: `echo $start`and `echo $end` show the output

Comment: @entiendoNull, Yes, using `http_build_query` worked, I'll post the exact answer in an edit, thank you.

Comment: @Riaan, I just added an answer before I saw your comment. Feel free to mark it as the right one if it served you. Others with a similar problem may benefit from your question and the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$arr = array('fromDate' => $start->toDateTimeString(),'toDate' => $end->addHours(24)->toDateTimeString());
$url = 'https://www.api.com/KML/PositionHistory?';   
$url .= http_build_query($arr,'','&');


$contents = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: Just had to adjust this a bit, check my answer in the post. Got an example from the PHP docs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Carbon is returning timestamps that contain spaces which are then being mishandled in the URL. You need to encode the timestamp before placing it in the URL using urlencode. Then on the receiving side use urldecode before utilizing the GET data.

Answer (score 0):

use `urlencode()` and `trim()`

```
$start = new Carbon($request->date_start);
$end = new Carbon($request->date_end);

$url = "https://www.api.com/KML/PositionHistory?fromDate=" . urlencode($start->toDateTimeString()) . "&toDate=" . urlencode($end->addHours(24)->toDateTimeString());

$url = trim($url); // use trim 

$contents = file_get_contents($url);
```